# Android notifications speedy_c2dm

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails

First time user of sending android Push messages from rails server.
Using https://github.com/sghael/speedy_c2dm
Have registered my project with Google and with the project ID getting the Registration_ID of the Android device.
Now, trying test.rb below, but nothing gets sent to phone.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup(:default, :development)
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'lib'))
$LOAD_PATH.unshift(File.dirname(__FILE__))
require 'speedy_c2dm'


TEST_EMAIL = "my_push_email@gmail.com"
TEST_PASSWORD = "MY_PASSWORD"
TEST_REGISTRATION_ID = "DEVICE_TOKEN_RECEIVED_FROM_PHONE"

speedyC2DM = SpeedyC2DM::API.new(TEST_EMAIL, TEST_PASSWORD)

options = {
  :registration_id => TEST_REGISTRATION_ID,
  :message => "Hi!",
  :extra_data => 42,
  :collapse_key => "some-collapse-key"
}


response = speedyC2DM.send_notification(options)
```

Any suggestion.. if I am missing anything..?

Comment: Android C2DM is deprecated, Google had introduced GCM as a replacement of C2DM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`speedy_c2dm 1.0.2`

> AFAIK **Speedy C2DM efficiently sends push notifications to Android
>   devices via google c2dm.**

But as  [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/) says you should Use **`GCM`** Instead.

> **Important:** C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012.
>   This means that C2DM has stopped accepting new users and quota
>   requests. No new features will be added to C2DM. However, apps using
>   C2DM will continue to work. Existing C2DM developers are encouraged to
>   migrate to the new version of C2DM, called [Google Cloud Messaging for
>   Android (GCM)](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). See the C2DM-to-GCM [Migration](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/c2dm.html) document for more
>   information. Developers must use GCM for new development.